# QListWidgetItem when button clicked do actions

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

I have a QListWidget with some items. I did this to select an item from QListWidget:

```
connect(ui->mylist,SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)),this,SLOT(onMyListItem(QListWidgetItem*)));
```

Now in onMyListItem function I did this to check the index of the item:

```
int index=ui->mylist->currentRow();
    qDebug()<<"index item: "<<index;
```

How can I do some actions when I select an item and click a showBtn button?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a button to your QListWidget , create an slot and connect your button signal to slot. by clicking the button , you can check witch item is selected and you can do what you want

Comment: I'm not adding a button to QListWidget. I need to choose something from the list and then click other button to make some actions depending on the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the button you're adding is a `QAction`, then you just need to connect its `triggered()` signal to a slot you create, say `makeAction()`:

```
connect(someAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(makeAction());
```

Inside this slot, assuming it has access to the list, you can get the current item in the list and do the appropriate thing:

```cpp
void makeAction()
{
    auto item = ui->mylist->currentItem();
    if (item)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```